# Pair up elements of a sequence without overlap

Tags: f#

I have a sequence (in this case actually an array) like this:

```
[| 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10|]
```

And want to produce a sequence of pairs like this:

```
[(1, 2); (3, 4); (5, 6); (7, 8); ...]
```

The following code works, but I can't help feeling that it's a lot of code. Is there a shorter, more idiomatic or more elegant way to do this.

```
[| 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10|]
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.mapi (fun i t -> (i, t))
|> Seq.filter (fun (i, t) -> i % 2 = 0)
|> Seq.map (fun (i, t) -> t)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
[| 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10|]
|> Seq.chunkBySize 2
|> Seq.choose (function [|x; y|] -> Some (x, y) | _ -> None)
```

So, `chunkBySize` will create a sequence like `seq [ [|1; 2|]; [|3; 4|]; .. ]`

Then `choose` will try to match each element of the sequence with an array of two elements, everything else will be filtered out, which accounts for a trailing array of a single element if the input length is not even.

It could be even shorter by changing the last line to:

```
|> Seq.collect Array.pairwise
```

Which would map `pairwise` to the each element, transforming for instance `[|1;2|]` to `[|(1;2)|]` and it will return `[||]` when there are less than two elements. So this will return a sequence of an array but since I'm using `collect` it will concatenate all elements. Since single elements were transformed to empty arrays it will concatenate nothing in those cases, if you think about it this is similar to the mechanics of `choose`.

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about `Seq.chunkBySize`! That's great. I presume you used `Seq.choose` to avoid a 1-tuple at the end in case the input had an odd number of elements?

Comment: Obviously this code is shorter but could you provide a little explanation of why it is simpler, for the OP and future readers?

Comment: Done, hope it helps !